# Add a "Select All" checkbox to lists of checkboxes that update an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, d3.js

I have two lists of checkboxes (there will be additional lists later), for example:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange()" name="job" rel="it-manager" value="IT-Manager" id="IT Manager" class="selectedId" checked> IT Manager</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange()" name="job" rel="consultant" value="Consultant" id="Consultant" class="selectedId" checked> Consultant</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange()" name="reg" rel="client" value="Client" id="Client" checked> Client</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange()" name="reg" rel="prospect" value="Prospect" id="Prospect" checked> Prospect</li>
<ul>
```

Whenever combinations of checkboxes are selected/deselected, an array of objects is filtered.

QUESTION What would be the best approach to adding a "Select All" box at the top? I want the functionality to be just like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/K9P8A/13/). I've tried implementing that example and the checkbox functionality works perfectly, but I can't seem to get the filter to update properly.

I've tried `if else` statements in `filteredBy` to no avail. I've tried an additional window function to handle just the "Select All" button, but that is screwing things up.

I realize this is a somewhat vague question, but am hoping maybe someone has run into this before. I am appreciative of any suggestions that can point me in the right direction. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/7bv51p5L/15/) Thanks!

**MORE DETAIL FOR CONTEXT** Whenever combinations of checkboxes are selected/deslected `onchange` in the input tags runs the `handleChange()` function, which filters an array of objects called `sorted` and puts the result in the var `arrayToFilterUpon`. It also runs a function called `makeFilteredArray` on that var.

```
window.handleChange = function() {
    arrayToFilterUpon = sorted.filter(filterBy);
    makeFilteredArray(arrayToFilterUpon);
}
```

The `makeFilteredArray` function just puts that into a new array `filteredArray` which is used to update a d3 map.

```
function makeFilteredArray(array) {
    var filteredArray = [];
    filteredArray.push(array);
```

Currently, the filter returns objects in the array when property values match checked (using "and" logic).

```
function filterBy(e) {
    return document.getElementById(e.jobRole).checked
    && document.getElementById(e.regType).checked;
}
```

And every time a checkbox change is made, the var `filteredArray` is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some help off line and the solution for my particular case is below. Realize this was a vague and sprawling question and that the solution that worked for me does directly answer it and does not relate exactly to the code in the question. Considering just deleting this question, but will leave it for now in case this answer is useful for anyone as a starting point for setting up Select All buttons in multiple lists.

```
setupSelectAll: function () {
    $('.selectedId').change(function () {
        var $input = $(this);

        var $allInputs = $input
            .closest('ul')
            .find('.selectedId');

        var $selectAll = $input.closest('ul').find('.selectAll');

        var totalInputs = $allInputs.length;
        var numberChecked = $allInputs.filter(":checked").length;

        $selectAll.prop('checked', totalInputs === numberChecked);
    });
},

setupChangeHandler: function () {
    var app = this;
    $('.job-role-filter .selectedId, .reg-type-filter .selectedId').change(
        _.debounce(function (){
            var $input = $(this);

            app.updateMap();
            app.updateChart();
        }, 100)
    );

    $('.selectAll').change(function (){
        var $selectAll = $(this);

        $selectAll.closest('ul')
            .find('.selectedId')
            .prop('checked', $selectAll.prop('checked'))
            .change();
    });
},

getCheckedOptions: function () {
    this._checkedOptions = {
        jobRole: $('.job-role-filter input:checked').map(function () {
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }),
        regType: $('.reg-type-filter input:checked').map(function () {
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }),
    };
},
```